# SetImageDrawable always return null pointer - Picasso Android

Tags: android, image, picasso

i've circleimageview that extends to imageview . this one is a code of my circle image view.

public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

```
private Paint mPaint;
private float mFrameSize;
private int mFrameColor;
private int mBorderColor;
private float mBorderSize;

private RectF mDstRectf;

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView);

    if(a != null) {
        setFrameSize(a.getInteger(R.styleable.CircleImageView_frameSize, 5));
        setFrameColor(a.getInteger(R.styleable.CircleImageView_frameColor, Color.WHITE));
        setBorderColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_borderColor, Color.BLACK));
        setBorderSize(a.getInteger(R.styleable.CircleImageView_borderSize, 1));
        a.recycle();
    }

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mDstRectf = new RectF(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
    super.setAlpha(alpha);
    mPaint.setAlpha((int) alpha);
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if(! (drawable instanceof CircleBitmapDrawble)){
        BitmapDrawable bmdrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        setImageBitmap(bmdrawable.getBitmap());
    }else{
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
    return;
}

@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
            resId);
    setImageBitmap(bm);
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    setImageDrawable(new CircleBitmapDrawble(getResources(), bm));
}

@Override
public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    //ignore setPadding
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //drawFrameArea
    if(mFrameSize > 0){
        drawFrameArea(canvas);
    }

    //fill Circle
    if(getDrawable() != null){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}

private void drawFrameArea(Canvas canvas) {
    mPaint.setColor(getFrameColor());
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    mDstRectf.set(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    canvas.drawCircle(mDstRectf.centerX(), mDstRectf.centerY(), Math.min(mDstRectf.width()/2, mDstRectf.height()/2), mPaint);

    if(getBorderSize() > 0){
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderSize);
        mPaint.setColor(getBorderColor());
        mDstRectf.inset( mBorderSize / 2, mBorderSize / 2);

        canvas.drawCircle(mDstRectf.centerX(), mDstRectf.centerY(), Math.min(mDstRectf.width()/2, mDstRectf.height()/2), mPaint);
    }
}

public float getFrameWith() {
    return mFrameSize;
}

public void setFrameSize(int frameSize) {
    mFrameSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP
            , frameSize
            , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    int padding = (int) mFrameSize;
    super.setPadding(padding,padding,padding,padding);
}

public int getFrameColor() {
    return mFrameColor;
}

public void setFrameColor(int color) {
    mFrameColor = color;
}

public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor;
}

public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
    mBorderColor = borderColor;
}

public float getBorderSize(){
    return mBorderSize;
}

private void setBorderSize(int borderSize) {
    mBorderSize = (float) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP
            , borderSize
            , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

}

i want to get an image from url with picasso . but it always said that my view is null . i've tried to setdrawable by code and it work.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(photo);
```

Error point to :

```
@Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if(! (drawable instanceof CircleBitmapDrawble)){
            BitmapDrawable bmdrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            setImageBitmap(bmdrawable.getBitmap()); //this one
        }else{
            super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
        return;
    }
```